# notifyDataSetChanged not working when open the App

Tags: android

I've read so many posts here in Stackoverflow about this problem... I implemented all the solution that I've seen, but none of them worked.

What is happening: the notifyDataSetChanged doesn't work when opening the app. If I change orientation or change the sort (popular to top rated, or vise-versa), it works. I debbuged the code and the data arrives correctly in the Adapter, but the notify doesn't work, so the interface doesn't got updated.

Can anyone help me, please?

My onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Resources rs = getResources();
    int numColumns = rs.getInteger(R.integer.list_columns);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_popular_movies);
    mErrorMessageDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_error_message_display);
    mLoadingIndicator = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_loading_indicator);

    //Resource based on https://discussions.udacity.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-fit-columns-in-gridlayoutmanager/221936/4
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, numColumns);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mPopularMoviesAdapter = new PopularMoviesAdapter(this, this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPopularMoviesAdapter);

    loadMoviesData(NetworkUtils.POPULAR_SORT);
}
```

The loadMoviesData method simply calls the execute() from AsyncTask.

My onPostExecute code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onPostExecute");
    mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if(result != null){
        showMoviesDataView();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Movies data = gson.fromJson(result, Movies.class);
        mPopularMoviesAdapter.setMovieList(data);
    } else {
        showErrorMessage();
    }
}
```

My setMovieList method:

```
public void setMovieList(Movies movieList) {
    this.movieList = movieList;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

My full code: https://github.com/guuilp/PopularMovies

Comment: It's better to post small snippets of code that you think are relevant. Is it the `onCreate()` method that has the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @Jack! I changed the original post, with code samples. I don't think it's only on the onCreate method that has the problem. 

I explain why: this project is to show popular/top rated movies, based on what the user selects. When opening the App, it shows the Popular (in blank). If I check the Popular again (it's a option in action bar), the Popular is shown. If I check the Top rated for the first time, the same problem: blank list. But, if I check again, is populated correctly.

Comment: You have tried doing loadMoviesData(NetworkUtils.POPULAR_SORT) before mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPopularMoviesAdapter) ?

Comment: No, @Diekrul. I'm gonna try. But doing this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Diekrul, didn't work :(

Comment: Did you check if `movieList` really contains data?

Comment: Yes, @Divers. I put a break point in the "this.notifyDataSetChanged();" line and Inspected the movieList. It has data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a look at your code and your `notifyDataSetChanged()` is working, the problem is that your `RecyclerView` has no height.

Change it to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.

[image]

Comment: Lifesaver!! That was the problem. I apologize for everyone that I said the problem was with the notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: Luis just beat me to it!! Awesome!